# PHP scraping text from a specific class on another website

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I want to create a script to automatically grab the text located within a specific class on a wikipedia page. For example, I want to get the musician Avicii's real name (Tim Bergling) from his wikipedia page. From google's inspect element I found that his name is stored in a class called "nickname":

```
<td class="nickname">Tim Bergling</td>
```

I would like to get the contents of the nickname class. I found a few threads that helped me out with some of the code, but I cannot get it to work correctly. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$wiki= file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avicii");
preg_match("/\<td class\=\"nickname\"\>(.*?)\<\/td\>/",$wiki,$n);
print $n; 

?>
```

Ultimately I want this name sent to a specific class on my website where it will be displayed. For now, I would just be content getting it to print. Thanks :)

Edit: I should clarify that I'm very new to PHP and coding in general, but I've picked it up quick and I'm trying to push myself. I appreciate your time very much!

Comment: I think it's easier done client side with jquery's `ajax()` function

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with jquery, but not ajax() in particular. I will see what I can find and give it a shot. Thanks for the reply. If anyone knows how to accomplish this in php that would great. Eventually I want to write another function that automatically searches for the wikipedia page of each musician and then calls the function to scrape the name, hometown, etc... off of the wiki page. I don't know if all that is possible in jquery or what language would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `DOMDocument` class instead of `preg_match`,try :

```
$html = file_get_contents("your url");
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
$classname = 'nickname';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm getting an error while trying to run it. "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in "my site" on line 9.

Comment: oh sorry, replace $xpath with $finder, my bad